# dictionary values as column labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have the following `dict`:

```
packetsNeeded = { u'hydrogen': 150,
                  u'helium': 143,
                  u'lithium': 122}
```

I am using **matplotlib** to plot a bar graph for each of the keys and the values of the dictionary above. I have managed to plot the bar chart using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pplot

pplot.bar(range(len(packetsNeeded)), packetsNeeded.values(),
         width = 0.75, align = 'center')
pplot.xticks(range(len(packetsNeeded)), packetsNeeded.keys())

pplot.xlabel("X label")
pplot.ylabel("Y label")
pplot.title("title here")
pplot.show()
```

I can show the *X-Axis* as the keys mentioned in the dictionary but I want the vertical bar chart to show the values of the dictionary on each bar.

I tried

```
pplot.yticks(range(len(packetsNeeded), packets.needed.values())
```

but the plot is as follows:
[image: yticks messes the y axis up!!]

What is the right way to show the labels on columns for a dict

I tried the following:

```
for a, b in zip( key(), value()):
    pplot.text(a, b, str(b))
```

but I run into problems

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you use your code you should get values on the y-axis (0 to 160 as it happens). Do you want these values to be written on the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've meant something along the lines of

```
for key, x in zip(packetsNeeded.keys(), range(len(packetsNeeded))): 
    pplot.text(x, packetsNeeded[key], packetsNeeded[key])
```

Comment: I want the values to be shown on the bars. for instance the bar of hydrogen should have the value on it.